# Highcharts: How can I change the clockwise color?

Tags: highcharts

I have searched everywhere on how to change the clockwise color of the speedometer without any luck.

If someone knows how to do it I will be really grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: I can't show some code because I don't know the code that handle the color of the clockwise. I want to chance the black color of the hand of the clock into another color.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the green, yellow, and red bands seen [here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/46-gauges-ranges-and-polar-charts-in-beta#gauges)?

If so look at:

```
   yaxis:{
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    }
```

Comment: No, the hand of the clock. That's color black? I wanna chance it into another color.

Comment: Nevermind, I found what I was looking for. It's under plotOptions.gauge.dial if someone is wondering.